# Extracting a substring, and INCLUDING the reference characters in the extraction

Tags: python

I found this portion of code on another post and although I have managed to stumble upon getting the correct output, I am pretty sure there is a cleaner way to go about it.

Although there are many posts with similar questions, I have not found any where the characters to find the index of are also included in the extraction...

I am essentially looking to extract `B08BY4V3NW`.

Can anyone share a more concise way to achieve this?

```
s1 = "sp - disc - auto - B08BY4V3NW - 18cb mold"
s2 = "B0"

print (s1[s1.index(s2) - len(""):-12])
```

Comment: Are you okay with using `regex`?

Comment: `len("")` would just be 0, wouldn't it?

Comment: Is `s1` going to be always of this type?

Comment: you could use something like this: `re.findall(s2+r"[a-zA-Z0-9]+", s1)`

Comment: len("") is 0, yes, but in the post I found this in, len had a value, and I don't know how to remove len and still make this work...

Comment: s1 will always be a string type

Comment: I am up for trying to use regex although I never have

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

tokens = word_tokenize(s1)
str_match =  [w for w in tokens if s2 in w]
```

**EDIT :**

```
s1 = "sp - disc - auto - B08BY4V3NW - 18cb mold"
s2 = "B0"
tokens = str.split(s1)
```

The `str.split(s1)` will return :

```
['sp', '-', 'disc', '-', 'auto', '-', 'B08BY4V3NW', '-', '18cb', 'mold']
```

Then, you can find your *string* by following from the list:

**1. Using list comprehension**

```
str_match =  [w for w in tokens if s2 in w]

print(str_match)
['B08BY4V3NW']
```

**2. Using filter**

```
str_match = list(filter(lambda x: s2 in x, tokens))

print(str_match)
['B08BY4V3NW']
```

**3. Using re**

```
import re
str_match = [x for x in tokens if re.search(s2, x)]

print(str_match)
['B08BY4V3NW']
```

If you want `B08BY4V3NW` as string format, you can use :

```
str_ = ''.join(str_match)
type(str_)

str
```

Comment: `nltk` might be overkill where it seems like `s1.split()` would work, but OP hasn't given any context so IDK.

Comment: Would you be willing to provide an example of what this would look like using split()?  I have tried using this already with indexing the location of s2 but also could not get this to work...

Comment: @acaciagrove I edit my answer